# Windows.Activated in wpf fires multiple times

Tags: wpf, windows

Hi I have a code to be written while window(WPF window) activate like clicking on the window or using alt/tab. The window is the child of a main form (windows app). I have used ToolWindow as the windowstyle.

It has a xamdatagrid which has to updated on activation

Problem is it fires multiple times. It should be fired once. I don not want my code to run multiple times

How to make it work. please help

Comment: Windows.Activated is invoked every time your window is bring on top or you disable / enable window.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it done.
I was using the below code

```
 private void OnAttributeHistoryWindowActivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        var win = ((RoutedEventArgs)(e)).Source as AttributeHistoryWindow;
       //My Code
 }
```

The first line of code was firing back the Activated event. And it never goes to the next line of my code.

Now I used below code and it works.

```
 private void OnAttributeHistoryWindowActivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       var win = sender as AttributeHistoryWindow;
       //My Code
 }
```

Now it fires once.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`Window.Activated` Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.activated(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN:

> Occurs when a window becomes the foreground window.

The `Window.Activated` Event is *supposed* to be called multiple times, so perhaps it is not the best event for you to handle. Alternatively, you could add a `bool isFirstTime` variable and use it to restrict your code to only being called once. Take this example:

```
private bool isFirstTime = true;

...

private void WindowActivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isFirstTime)
    {
        isFirstTime = false;
        // do something here just once
    }
}
```

However, as (from the linked page)...

> A window is activated (becomes the foreground window) when:
>
> • The window is first opened.
> • A user switches to a window by selecting it with the mouse, pressing ALT+TAB, or from Task Manager.
> • A user clicks the window's taskbar button.

... you may find that this will not work for you.